# Actualizar celda si uno de los campos es igual al agregar filas desde un TextBox

Tags: vb.net

Tengo dos `DataGridView` las siguientes columnas:

- CODIGO
- NOMBRE
- CANTIDAD.

A través de `TextBox` y un `botón`, estoy pasando valores de un `DataGridView` a otro, agregando nuevas filas.

¿Es posible lograr que al encontrar valores idénticos en `CODIGO` y `NOMBRE`, aumente la `CANTIDAD`, actualizando esa fila, sin crear una nueva?

Este es mi código:

```
Dim newRow As DataRowView = DirectCast(Pedidos_GeneralBindingSource.AddNew(), DataRowView)

newRow("CODIGO") = CODIGOTextBox.Text
newRow("NOMBRE") = NOMBRETextBox.Text
newRow("CANTIDAD") = CANTIDADTextBox.Text
```

---

**EDITADO**

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
Dim DT_Segundo As New DataTable
DT_Segundo.Columns.Add("CODIGO", Type.[GetType]("System.String"))
DT_Segundo.Columns.Add("NOMBRE", Type.[GetType]("System.String"))
DT_Segundo.Columns.Add("CANTIDAD", Type.[GetType]("System.String"))

Dim primarykey(1) As DataColumn
primarykey(0) = DT_Segundo.Columns("CODIGO")
DT_Segundo.PrimaryKey = primarykey

DataGridView2.DataSource = DT_Segundo

Dim CODIGOi As String
Dim NOMBREi As String
Dim CANTIDADi As String

CODIGOi = CODIGOTextBox.Text
NOMBREi = NOMBRETextBox.Text
CANTIDADi = CANTIDADTextBox.Text

If Not DT_Segundo.Rows.Find(CODIGOi) Is Nothing Then
    DT_Segundo.Rows.Find(CODIGOi).Item("CANTIDAD") = DT_Segundo.Rows.Find(CODIGOi).Item("CANTIDAD") + CANTIDADi
Else
    DT_Segundo.Rows.Add(CODIGOi, NOMBREi, CANTIDADi)
End If
```

Mi problema está ahora en que al ejecutarlo, reemplazo los valores existentes de mi DataGridView2 por una fila creada a partir de los valores alojados en los TextBox. No agrega nuevas filas ni suma la cantidad para aquellas que tienen mismo valor en la columna "CODIGO".

---

**EDITADO 2**

Agregue la columna COSTO para calcular valor y finalmente pude lograrlo con otro código, lo dejo para aquel que le pueda servir:

```
    Dim Found As Boolean = False
    Dim total As Double = Convert.ToDouble(COSTOTextBox.Text) * 1
    If Pedidos_GeneralDataGridView.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Pedidos_GeneralDataGridView.Rows
            If Convert.ToString(row.Cells(0).Value) = CODIGOTextBox.Text Then

                row.Cells(2).Value = Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells(2).Value))
                row.Cells(3).Value = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells(3).Value) + Convert.ToDouble(COSTOTextBox.Text)
                Found = True
            End If
        Next
        If Not Found Then

            Dim newRow As DataRowView = DirectCast(Pedidos_GeneralBindingSource.AddNew(), DataRowView)

            newRow("CODIGO") = CODIGOTextBox.Text
            newRow("NOMBRE") = NOMBRETextBox.Text
            newRow("CANTIDAD") = CANTIDADTextBox.Text
            newRow("COSTO") = COSTOTextBox.Text

        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código para crear el origen de datos para el segundo DataGridView y asignarselo.

```
Dim DT_Segundo as New Datatable
DT_Segundo.Columns.Add("Codigo", Type.GetType("System.String"))
DT_Segundo.Columns.Add("Nombre", Type.GetType("System.String"))
DT_Segundo.Columns.Add("Cantidad", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
DT_Segundo.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {DT_Segundo.Columns("Codigo"), DT_Segundo.Columns("Nombre")}
DataGridView2.DataSource = DT_Segundo
```

Una vez que tienes eso, lo que debes hacer en la porción de código que compartiste es:

```
Dim CodigoIngresado as String
Dim NombreIngresado as String
Dim CantidadIngresada As String

CodigoIngresado = CODIGOTextBox.Text
NombreIngresado = NOMBRETextBox.Text
CantidadIngresada = CANTIDADTextBox.Text 

If Not DT_Segundo.Rows.Find({CodigoIngresado,NombreIngresado}) Is Nothing Then
DT_Segundo.Rows.Find({CodigoIngresado,NombreIngresado}).Item("Cantidad") = DT_Segundo.Rows.Find({CodigoIngresado,NombreIngresado}).Item("Cantidad") + CantidadIngresada 
Else
DT_Segundo.Rows.Add(CodigoIngresado,NombreIngresado,CantidadIngresada)
End If
```

De esta manera, y gracias a que definimos a la columna Código y a la columna Nombre como Clave Primaria, podemos buscar una fila que ya exista con el código y nombre a agregar, y si es así sumarle la cantidad indicada.

**EDIT**: *(En base a más datos aportados en comentarios)*

Luego del .Fill que comentas, añade la linea de código que define la clave primaria doble:

```
Me.Pedidos_GeneralTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PedidosDataSet.Pedido‌​s_General) 
 PedidosDataSet.Pedido‌​s_General.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {PedidosDataSet.Pedido‌​s_General.Columns("Codigo"), PedidosDataSet.Pedido‌​s_General.Columns("Nombre")}
DataGridView2.DataSource = PedidosDataSet.Pedido‌​s_General
```

Luego en donde hacemos la comprobación nos queda:

```
Dim CodigoIngresado as String
Dim NombreIngresado as String
Dim CantidadIngresada As String

CodigoIngresado = CODIGOTextBox.Text
NombreIngresado = NOMBRETextBox.Text
CantidadIngresada = CANTIDADTextBox.Text 

If Not PedidosDataSet.Pedido‌​s_General.Rows.Find({CodigoIngresado,NombreIngresado}) Is Nothing Then
PedidosDataSet.Pedido‌​s_General.Rows.Find({CodigoIngresado,NombreIngresado}).Item("Cantidad") = PedidosDataSet.Pedido‌​s_General.Rows.Find({CodigoIngresado,NombreIngresado}).Item("Cantidad") + CantidadIngresada 
Else
PedidosDataSet.Pedido‌​s_General.Rows.Add(CodigoIngresado,NombreIngresado,CantidadIngresada)
End If
```

Comment: Hola Agustin. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, es realmente de mucha ayuda.
Pude escribir el código en VB.NET, pero estoy teniendo un problema: al hacer click en mi botón estoy borrando todos los datos existentes en mi DataGridView2 y colocando los valores alojados en cada TextBox. No suma ni agrega.
Creo que el problema está en esta línea:

DataGridView2.DataSource = DT_Segundo

Puede ser?

Comment: Es correcto, ya que con el código que te estoy pasando estamos creando un nuevo origen de datos para ese DataGridView2. Para poder ayudarte necesito saber el código con el que llenas la propiedad DataSource del DataGridView2, así lo podemos reemplazar.

Comment: Tengo una tabla en Access, cargada como origen de datos. Al iniciar el formulario tengo el código: Me.Pedidos_GeneralTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PedidosDataSet.Pedidos_General)

Comment: Revisa el edit de mi respuesta, quizás ahí está tu solución.

Comment: Agustin, ya pude correr el código y creería que está todo bien escrito, sin embargo, tengo un error al ejecutarlo. La tabla a la cual le estoy asignando como clave primaria las columnas CODIGO y NOMBRE tiene registros iguales en esos campos, por lo tanto, no me deja iniciarla.
Se te ocurre alguna solución?

Comment: Es un problema de conceptos entonces, ya que como tú lo dices si utilizas una clave doble es porque en teoria no deberías tener registros duplicados.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo primero recorrer las filas que tengas en el DataGridView que estés usando *(no es muy claro en tu pregunta este punto)*, y compara si existe una fila que tenga los mismos valores que tienen tus campos de texto.

El siguiente pseudo-código ilustra mi explicación:

> NOTA: No copies y pegues el código, entiéndelo primero y ajusta tu
>   código.

```
// Obtén los valores de los campos de texto
Dim txtCodigo As String = CODIGOTextBox.Text
Dim txtNombre As String = NOMBRETextBox.Text
Dim txtCantidad As Double = Double.Parse(CANTIDADTextBox.Text)

// Recorre las filas de tu DataGridView1 (o el que estés usando).
Foreach (fila in DataGridView1)
BeginForeach
   // Si esta fila tiene el código y el nombre iguales a los valores
   // de los textboxes...
   if (fila["CODIGO"] == txtCodigo && fila["NOMBRE"] == txtNombre)
   BeginIf
       // Actualiza la CANTIDAD:
       // Edit: Sumar la cantidad de la fila con el valor del TextBox:
       fila["CANTIDAD"] += txtCantidad
   EndIf
EndForeach
```

Comment: Mauricio, gracias por tu respuesta. Entiendo tu código y estoy queriendo aplicarlo. ¿Qué opción tengo si en ves de reemplazar la CANTIDAD con txtCantidad, necesito sumar ambas? Es decir, sumar el TextBox de Cantidad con el valor que está en esa columna.
Saludos!

Comment: @LucianoMinetti, he editado mi respuesta, yo estoy mas familiarizado con C#, por lo que debes ver de nuevo mi respuesta y hacer los ajustes que consideres.

Comment: Ok, excelente. Estoy intentando adaptarlo a vb.net.
De todas formas, esta idea no me serviría para que aquellos registros que no son iguales se agreguen como nueva fila, no?

Comment: Puedo editarlo, pero lo omití porque es posible que la fila exista en la siguiente iteración. [Mira la respuesta de Agustín M.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67221/78) para ver cómo agregar la nueva fila "si no existe" - (después del if) :) . Saludos.